# MySQL output hex string as UTF-8

Tags: mysql, string, utf-8, character-encoding, hex

This works UTF8

```
create temporary table test (x char(1) not null) charset=utf8;
insert into test select x'c3a9';
select hex(x), x from test;
drop table test;
```

outputs

```
+--------+---+
| hex(x) | x |
+--------+---+
| C3A9   | é | 
+--------+---+
```

But this uses the default charset which is not utf8

```
SELECT x'c3a9';
```

How can I change the above one-liner to output UTF-8 `é` instead of `Ã©`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(x'c3a9' USING utf8)
```

should work. See [*11.10. Cast Functions and Operator*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html).